# Adding to the context menu in office plugin with c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, contextmenu, office365

I am creating an office 2016 plugin for Microsoft Outlook, and would like to customize the context menu (right click menu) by adding elements when I right click on a calendar event.

Previously  `ApplicationEvents_11_Event.ItemContextMenuDisplayevent`

and its functions would get the job done but it seems to be deprecated and no longer supported. Is there a new option for me if I would like to edit the context menu in Outlook 2016 with c#? I am using visual studio 2015 community and the Outlook 2013 and 2016 VSTO add-in template.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is used for customizing context menus in Outlook 2010 and above. Read more about context menus in the articles:

- [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

The UI is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Finally, in case of VSTO add-ins take a look at the [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks for the help!